# How to keep water away from house from new concrete pad?

Tags: concrete, deck, waterproofing, self-leveling-concrete

I am planning to build a concrete pad under my deck (8-10' clearance). I am concerned about water dripping down through my deck and collecting against my house. What tips/steps should I take to prevent this when I build/pour the pad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your key design element for the concrete pad will be the slope that you plan for the surface away from the house. This allows water to run down slope rather than gathering at the house. Another detail will be the attention paid to getting a flat surface without dips and pockets of unevenness where water could collect.